# How do I find out who is making a lot of requests to the server?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

I am running Apache server and would like to find out who (IP address) is making a lot of request for the last 24 hours using command line. Also like to find out who has the most open connection at the moment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am running Apache server and would like to find out who (IP address)
>   is making a lot of request for the last 24 hours using command line.

```
awk '/29\/Sep\/2011/ { print $1 }' /path/to/access_log | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head
```

> Also like to find out who has the most open connection at the moment?

```
netstat -natp | grep httpd | awk '{ print $5 }' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head
```

Comment: `sort|uniq -c|sort -rn|` == `sort -ucrn`?

Comment: No, `-uc` check for strict ordering: _sort: -:2: disorder: IP_

Comment: You're right. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tail /path/to/apache_log_file` (check in `/var/log/apache2`). One way to see current connections is to use [mod_status](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html). You can also use `netstat -a |grep www`